# Override SVG transform attributes with CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG element that looks like this:

```
<image
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  overflow="visible"
  width="54"
  height="54"
  id="Content-Author-Off_xA0_Image"
  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..."
  transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 108)">
</image>
```

Is it possible to override `transform` attribute with CSS? I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
image {
    transform: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `transform: none` doesn't quite work in all browsers (see [bugreport](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415950)) (**fixed jan 2017**), but it's possible to work around that by using an identity matrix, e.g `transform: scale(1)`. The stylerules will override the attributes, as demonstrated by the following snippet:

```css
circle {
    transform-origin: 50%;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

circle:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" transform="translate(500 500)"/>
</svg>
```

Same as [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLtzajsm/).

Answer (score 2):

CSS cannot affect an attribute only a CSS property. You could try using a CSS transform instead of an SVG attribute transform in the first place, although not all UAs support CSS transforms on SVG elements yet.

Here's an example of a CSS transform with a rect element. Put the mouse over it to see it change.

```css
rect {
    transform: translate(50px, 0) rotate(30deg);
}

rect:hover {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="30" y="30" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```